# How to join a column from a line data layer attribute table and join it to a shapefile attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, attribute-joins, proximity

**Issue:**

I have calculated the distance from shore from point data showing dolphin IDs to the coastline by using these commands:

**Step 1: Digitise the country lines for administration country shapefiles into line data**

Vector - Geometry tools - Polygons to Lines

**Step 2: Turn the line data into point data**

Vector - Geometry tools - Extract Vertices

**Step 3: Calculate the distance to the coast**

Processing tools - Toolbox - Distance to nearest Hub

Now I have two attribute tables. The first attribute table is **my point data** showing dolphin IDs', and the second attribute table shows the **'Hubdistance' from the ' dolphin ID' to the coastline**.**

Both attribute tables have two columns in common called **'FID' and 'ID'.** I would like to export all the data eventually into a .csv file, hence this is why I would like all of my fields to be in one attribute table.

Does anyone know how I can join the column **Hubdistance (line data attribute table)** to my attribute table showing point data for my dolphin IDs?

**Line data attribute table showing Hubdistance:**

Both attribute tables have fields fid and id in common.

[image]

**The shapefile attribute table showing dolphin IDs**

[image]

Comment: Can you please show how does your data look like? Did you try the Join in QGIS : https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_table_joins.html

Comment: Hello Taras, I added screenshots showing the fields in both of my attribute tables. I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not see two fields "FID" and "ID" in the *'Motenegro_Hub_distance'* table. Otherwise you can work with a [Virtual Layer](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers), like: `SELECT d.*, h.*
FROM "dolphin" AS d
LEFT JOIN "hubdistance" AS h ON d.FID||d.ID = h.FID||h.ID;`